# coroutine not found for KMongo - kotlin backend with jwt

Tags: intellij-idea, ktor, kmongo

I am trying to implement kotlin backend with mongo DB and JWT, all requried dependencies are added as

```
ktor_version=2.1.0
kmongo_version=4.7.0
commons_codec_version=1.15
kotlin_version=1.6.21
logback_version=1.2.11
kotlin.code.style=official
```

But unable to get import for .coroutine

```
KMongo.createClient(connectionString = "....").coroutine.getDatabaseName(dbName)
```

error is still there even though the import is set manually

```
import org.litote.kmongo.coroutine.coroutine
```

[image]

Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-call-logging-jvm:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json-jvm:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth-jvm:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth-jwt-jvm:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm:$ktor_version")
implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm:$ktor_version")
testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")

implementation("org.litote.kmongo:kmongo:$kmongo_version")
implementation("org.litote.kmongo:kmongo-coroutine:$kmongo_version")

implementation("commons-codec:commons-codec:$commons_codec_version")
```

Comment: Could you please share the list with your Gradle dependencies?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman gradle dependencies added

Answer (score 3):

For KMongo, have to use following import

```
import org.litote.kmongo.reactivestreams.KMongo
```

Instead of

```
import org.litote.kmongo.KMongo
```